# Android app gets ClassNotFoundException after exported to apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I have a class defined at both server side and in the android app so it can be send through socket connection.
It was all fine when I'm running it by eclipse through USB, but it gets ClassNotFoundException when installed from apk file.

The class is in the same package with all other activities, so I don't understand why is this happening.
I've tried searching the problem, but seems like others have this exception on activity class. Not the same issue.
I've tried cleaning the project and fix project properties. Still the same.

Comment: What are the references from this class? Do they refer classes from Android package? Or from other 3-rd party jars that you missed to include in the project?

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: This class uses google calendar api. Do I have to do anything with that? It was added to my project by google plugin for eclipse.

Comment: I never noticed that but yes, there is a proguard folder in my project.

Comment: it seems like progaurd has skipped some of the referenced files, please check your logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proguard can remove your class. If you use proguard check it's logs. If you find that your class was removed add it to proguard config. When you instantiate objects via reflections proguard can't analize this and thinks that some classes never used. So it removes such classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to add the calendar library to the Android Private Libraries, so that it is exported with the apk. Generally all library files in libs folder are exported with the apk.

Comment: I have the calendar jar file in the libs folder. Seems like this is not the reason? Thank you anyway.

Comment: then maybe as mentioned in the comments for the question you need to check the proguard. Also have you checked this project http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html